# Exporting environment variable in bash script - it doesnt work

Tags: bash, shell, command

I wrote a little bash script to export environment variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Pass a path:"
read path
echo $path

defaultPath = /home/katie/Desktop

if [ -n "$path" ]; then
    echo "Path is empty! Exporting default path ..."
    export my_var=$defaultPath
else
    export my_var=$path
fi
```

but I got error:

> defaultPath: command not found

How to fix it?

**WORKNG VERSION:**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Pass a path:"
read path
echo $path

defaultPath=/home/user/Desktop

if [ -n "$path" ]; then
    export my_var=$path
else
    echo "Path is empty! Exporting default path ..."
    export my_var=$defaultPath
fi
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No whitespace is allowed surrounding the = in a variable assignment:

```
defaultPath=/home/katie/Desktop
```

With spaces, the line is interpreted as a simple command that attempts to execute the command `defaultPath` with two arguments, `=` and `/home/katie/Desktop`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked now but take a look how it worked: http://pastie.org/private/qlgozczj1nphfrdb1hvkw. Did I miss sth else?